# where is setHeaderData defined in pyside2 qsqltablemodel class inheritance from qabstractitemmodel?

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to understand where the setHeaderData virtual method is defined in qSqlTableModel class. I followed the inheritance chain up through the other classes but don't see it mentioned.

When I replace class MyClass(QSqlTableModel): with class MyClass(QAbstractTableModel):, everything works except I don't get column headings, just numbers; I also don't get an error about a virtual function not being defined.
The heading code works with the QSqlTableModel, just does not seem to do anything for QAbstractTableModel. It has to be defined somewhere in the QSqlTableModel to work. If I 'knew' what SetHeaderData did I could try to implement it, but I've not found any examples of its code, just mentions of it.

```
def set_header_data(self):
    """
    from __init__, load the headers into the model
    """
    for headix, head in enumerate(self._head):
        self.setHeaderData(headix, Qt.Horizontal, head, role=Qt.EditRole)
```

PySide2 5.15.2
Python 3.9.1

Comment: `setHeaderData()` is *implemented* in QSqlTableModel (actually, in the inherited QSqlQueryModel). Since you're using an abstract model, you need to implement that, by storing the data for the header and *both* return `True` if they are successfully stored *and* emit the `headerDataChanged` signal. See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setHeaderData)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the C++ doc. I did find it there as a reimplemented public function. It is not in the pyside2 version of the doc. I found the C++ code (/home/qt/qt5_coco/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.cpp
), but I can't figure out how to translate this "d->headers[section][role] = value;" into python as headers seems to be part of the C++ and I don't know what it is in python.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I had an epiphany, I think. I was wondering how the model connects the data to the view. Bam, it hit me. data() does it. So I need to write the headerData() method. It seems to be doing something, but I will have to correct a bunch of errors with data timing.

Comment: `headerData()` behaves exactly like `data()`, with the difference that the argument is not a QModelIndex, but the *logical index* of the section and the orientation. If you just want to return a standardized header, create a list of them in the init (or in the class), and return the item corresponding to the correct section/orientation if the role is `Qt.DisplayRole`

Comment: I FINALLY figured that out. Additionally I was missing this "return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)" which handled the verticals. Thank you for the pointers.